# Generic 1366 error using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have problems with mysql and my drupal 7 website.
With many modules who want to insert data in my bdd, i have the following error:

```
PDOException : SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'field_image54_width' at row 1: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_image54} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_image54_fid, field_image54_alt, field_image54_title, field_image54_width, field_image54_height) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 24 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 24 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => flexslidertest [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 51 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => ) dans field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (ligne 514 dans /home/sinus/Web/Mysite/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

If i change the type of field_image54_width from int to varchar it works but it's not a good solution, i think i need to change my sql configuration.

I'm on archlinux on localhost (on my computer).
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.18-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Server connection collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci and 
Collation tables are utf8_general_ci

Comment: You want an empty string to be inserted into a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: May be dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425568/incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000-date-sub-in-having

Comment: The problem is clear and i can manually resolve it but the errors appears on multiple modules. So, i think the problem is my mariadb configuration and not the modules. Also strict mod of mariadb is disabled.