# Incorrect DateTime Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' - Date_Sub() in Having

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

So I have an insert which looks like this:

```
  INSERT INTO TempDupeData (Sys_InvoiceID, DupeSetID, Netted, InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, Sys_SupplierID, SuppInvNo, NetAmount, VATAmount, GrossAmount, PayDate, PayRef,PayRefNo, PayType,
    PayAmount, Curr, GBPNetAmount, GBPVATAmount, GBPGrossAmount, NetAmountAbs, GrossAmountAbs, VATAmountAbs, DocType, SuppInvNoNums, VATPerc, VATA, VATB, VATC,
  VATD, VATE, VATPotentialClaim, ClaimStatus, SuppInvNoSubst, SuppInvNoSubstFlag, DupeSubstGross, DupeSubstNet, SuppInvNoCharMap, SuppInvNoCharMapFlag, SeqErrFlag)

    SELECT
      FK_SysInvoiceID,
      CONCAT(CTE.NetAmountAbs, CTE.AccountNumber),
      Netted,
      InvoiceNo,
      InvoiceDate,
      I.FK_SupplierID,
      SuppInvNo,
      NetAmount,
      VATAmount,
      GrossAmount,
      PayDate,
      PayRef,
      PayRefNo,
      PayType,
      PayAmount,
      Curr,
      GBPNetAmount,
      GBPVATAmount,
      GBPGrossAmount,
      CTE.NetAmountAbs,
      GrossAmountAbs,
      VATAmountAbs,
      DocType,
      SuppInvNoNums,
      VATPerc,
      VATA,
      VATB,
      VATC,
      VATD,
      VATE,
      VATPotentialClaim,
      ClaimStatus,
      SuppInvNoSubst,
      SuppInvNoSubstFlag,
      DupeSubstGrs,
      DupeSubstNet,
      SuppInvNoCharMap,
      SuppInvNoCharMapFlag,
      SeqErrFlag
    FROM (SELECT
        FK_SupplierID,
        AccountNumber,
        NetAmountAbs,
        CASE WHEN MIN(NetAmountAbs) < SUM(NetAmount) THEN 0 ELSE -1 END AS Netted

      FROM invoice
      WHERE NetAmountAbs >= 500 and InvoiceDate IS NOT null
      GROUP BY FK_SupplierID,
               NetAmountAbs
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      AND ((SUM(CASE WHEN NetAmount >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 1)
      AND (MAX(SuppInvNoNums) != MIN(SuppInvNoNums))
      AND (MIN(InvoiceDate) != MAX(InvoiceDate))
      AND (DATE_SUB(MAX(COALESCE(InvoiceDate, NOW())) <= MIN(COALESCE(InvoiceDate, NOW())), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
      AND (MAX(GrossAmountAbs) != MIN(GrossAmountAbs))) CTE
      INNER JOIN invoice I
        ON CTE.NetAmountAbs = I.NetAmountAbs
        AND CTE.FK_SupplierID = I.FK_SupplierID
    ORDER BY CTE.NetAmountAbs DESC, CTE.FK_SupplierID;
```

It takes from a table, performs some calculations, joins on itself and then inserts. It failed with this message: `Incorrect DateTime Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. I have narrowed it down and if I remove this line from the having clause `(DATE_ADD(MAX(COALESCE(InvoiceDate, NOW())) <= MIN(COALESCE(InvoiceDate, NOW())), INTERVAL -30 DAY))` it works.

In fact, it works when I remove the insert strangely.

The select doesn't return anything yet it still fails.

Why is this? Can anyone help find out why?

Comment: So if you just run the SELECT part of the query then you receive results back without error?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: And if you remove that DATE_ADD line from your HAVING clause then the whole INSERT works?

Comment: Again, that is the case

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First option:**

This warning probably could be due to the `SQL_MODE`.

According to mysql documentation "If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed.". So this may be the cause your `INSERT` with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' fails.

You can check your sql mode by executing this:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

and if any of the `NO_ZERO_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` are set, then you can just:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

**Second option**

The other option is it is failing because of the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode.
As mysql documentation say:

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid
>   date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and
>   inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is
>   not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as
>   well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted
>   and inserts produce a warning

The same is valid for datetime.

So you have to either disable STRICT MODE **OR** if disabling it is not an option - modify the query so it doesn't return invalid date/datetime result

Comment: Sorry, our sql mode is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. And I can insert a 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as a date separately, it's really strange

Comment: and what is the type of the failing column ?

Comment: It`s because of the strict mode. Try disabling it ... or if it is not an option modify the query so it doesn't return invalid date/datetime result.

Comment: You da real MVP bro. I used insert ignore. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it help you.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code before query

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

or
go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` & comment out `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

**useful note** [SQL STRICT MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)