# Even though the MySQL sql_mode doesn't contain NO_ZERO_DATE I'm still getting `Mysql2::Error: Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'`

Tags: mysql

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and MySQL 5.7.22

In my Rails Application I'm getting the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'datum_auftrag' at row 1: INSERT INTO `jobs` (`auftrags_nr`, `bemerkungen`) VALUES ('', '')
```

Regarding to [Incorrect DateTime Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' - Date_Sub() in Having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425568/incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000-date-sub-in-having)

I did 
`SET sql_mode = '';`

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
+--------+---------+
| global | session |
+--------+---------+
|        |         |
+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the error still remains. Why is that?

Comment: Removing everything from sql_mode is a slightly overreacted action. Try adding the time part to the date constant. `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: it's for testing purposes and i'm using date not datetime.